# Replacing escape characters in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, replace

Trying to replace all \ characters in a CSV to be \ so that they are read correctly. Here's my udf:

```
def escapeBackslash: String => String = _.replaceAll("[_\\]","\\\\")
def escapeBackslashUDF = udf(escapeBackslash)
```

\N is fine so I don't need to worry about those, but I'm getting the output:

```
123,myName\,myDesc,245,true
345,anotherName,\N,600,\N
789,name3,desc3,\N,false
```

Any help out there?

Here is the input:

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("id", StringType), StructField("name", StringType), StructField("dec", StringType), StructField("amount",IntegerType), StructField("enabled",BooleanType)))
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row("123", "myName\\", "myDesc",245, true), Row("345","anotherName",null,600,null), Row("789","name3","desc3",null,false)))
```

I am trying to get the following output to escape the :

```
123,myName\\,myDesc,245,true
345,anotherName,\N,600,\N
789,name3,desc3,\N,false
```

Comment: what else do you expect ?

Comment: What was your input? What was your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

What I did to fix this was write a UDF for every string field, registered the UDF, then sorted through each field to find strings and select those fields with the UDF.

```
val func:(String) => String = (test:String) => {
  Option(test) match{
    case Some(t) => t.replace("\\", "\\\\")
    case _ => <null>
  }
```

}

```
val fields = dfOut.schema.fields
  .map( col => {
    if (col.dataType.isInstanceOf[StringType]){  s"${EscapeBackslashUDF.name}(${col.name})"}
    else { s"${col.name}" }
  }).toSeq

super.write(target, dfOut.selectExpr(fields:_*) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Spark 1.5, you don't need to use an user-defined function for escaping backslash character. You can use [`regexp_replace`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#regexp_replace(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,pattern:String,replacement:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) as follow:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, regexp_replace}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType

dataframe.select(data.schema.fields.map(field => field.dataType match {
  case StringType => regexp_replace(col(field.name), "\\\\", "\\\\\\\\").as(field.name)
  case _ => col(field.name)
}): _*)
```

> Note: to match backslash when using `regexp_replace` you have to use `"\\\\"` pattern instead of `"\\"`.